# IE 11 Will not load systemjs

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I am working with SystemJS and I have a pseudo-bootstrapper file that I use to check to make sure certain conditions are met before the loading of the main scripts to execute the page load. Here is a snippet of that code.

```
var obj = document.createElement('script');
obj.src = 'jspm_packages/system.js';
document.body.appendChild(obj);
```

This code does NOT execute the script, yet it does load it with a 200 code as evidenced by the network tab within the IE dev tools. There should be a global object "System" created, but it does not exist. Looking through the DOM, the object is properly created and appended to the body.

Does anyone know if this is strictly an issue with IE and SystemJS? I have no idea what's going on. I'm pulling my hair out, as per usual with the demon that is IE. I should note that every other browser works as expected, providing the "System" global variable.

**EDIT** Further testing has assured that this is not an issue with appendChild, as other scripts using the same method, execute on load just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that IE versions < Edge do not support promises. I needed a polyfill for IE 11.

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467845(v=vs.85).aspx) tells us that your script may not run in IE11. The line in particular which is of interest is:

"Script elements with external resources should no longer execute during appendChild."

This appears to be what's happening.

**EDIT:** An alternate approach could be taken.

It would be a good idea to do condition checks on the server side before sending the response if you want to change page loading at the system.js level. If that is **not possible** then I'd suggest doing a redirect after the condition checks instead of appendChild.

Comment: Are there alternative methods for doing this? I feel like this is a common thing to do in web browsers these days with modular scripts.

Comment: There are a couple options. Keeping with the current idea you could try jquery's append() function to see if it does something behind the scenes(you have to load jquery thoughv :-( ).  I will edit my response with to suggest a different approach as well.

Comment: I'm not going to use jQuery for one method. I want a native approach. I will look through jQuery code though to see if they do something that makes it work, though I haven't tried jQuery to see if their append method works in IE for changing src attribute.

Comment: yeah, that's why there was a sad face because if you load jquery then you could have just loaded system.js anyway XD. It is correct to look into the jquery code to compare what it is doing.

Comment: It looks like jQuery uses an eval function on the scripts that are inserted. What doesn't make sense though is that the other script I'm setting the source for executes, the systemjs for some reason is the only one not executing.

Comment: I'm beginning to think more and more that this has to do with SystemJS not IE, at least in regards to IE compatibility with SystemJS.